# Can't make my web page fit to screen (fluid) and instead is too big to fit and scrolls horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am a student learning html/css and I am having trouble with my first website. I am having a lot of difficulty configuring the page so it is fluid instead of fixed. I have a box, image and some text configured so they would be absolute on the page but I can't get the page itself to be fluid to fit (and not be too big) for the browser.
This is the css/html :

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(49, 184, 184);
  width: 2023px;
  height: 842px;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 588px;
  top: 41px;
  width: 1376px;
  height: 927px;
}

.con {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 200px;
  color: white;
  width: 271px;
  height: 209px;
  left: 293px;
  top: 106px;
}

.view {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: rgba(0, 103, 103, 0.7);
  border-color: transparent;
  font-size: 200px;
  color: white;
  left: 588px;
  top: 104px;
  width: 396px;
  height: 212px;
}

html,
body,
square,
image,
con,
view {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>ConView</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <img src="indeximage.jpg" class="image">
  <p class="con">con</p>
  <p class="view">view</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's too much going on for me to give a real answer, but you can't easily construct a fluid layout with static units (px). Try % or vw/vh.

Comment: As suggested by @D_N use % or Flex

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with the above approach is the fixed width that has been assigned to different elements on the page. The Media Query would be your best friend in this regard. It allows you to know the device dimensions and different styles can be implemented to different device dimension constraints. In this particular case, you could set the browser dimension to be the width of the square instead of assigning a fixed width.
[Media Query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you should make another div and use it as a wrapper for other contents and set the property of wrapper div to 100% and place every other div inside the wrapper div and set inner divs widths to 100%.Also place the image inside a div it would  be easy for you to position your image